# Ember js version dependency

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

How I can understand which versions for plug-ins require my specific version of ember.js?

For example:

Ember v.1.3 requires:
ember-data v.1.0 beta
handlebars v1.0.0

But how I can understand which versions reuqires ember.js v1.7?
As example I need ember-data, ember-state, handebars.

Can anybody explain logic relations between versions to avoid such question in future?

Comment: https://github.com/components/ember/blob/1.7.0/bower.json Similarly you can look at the ember-data bower file. It can be easier to specify then check for conflicts, but you can always check first as a sanity check.

Answer (score 0):

Just look at the [bower.json](http://bower.io/docs/creating-packages/) files for the packages. Here's the one for [Ember.js](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/bower.json) and here's the one for [Ember-Data](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/bower.json).